# How to change startup window locations in Interface Builder

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch, interface-builder

Every time I open a .xib file the View window is partly covered by the Library panel, so I have to drag it to a different location. Is there a way to setup the locations of where windows appear when IB starts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no.